# Filling a DataTable with Firestore and Flutter (using StreamBuilder)

Tags: datatable, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

How to populate a DataTable using StreamBuilder?

Below is my code:

```
          new StreamBuilder(
            stream: widget._returnStreamWithActiveKeysOnly(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) return new Text('Loading...');
              return new DataTable(
                columns: <DataColumn>[
                  new DataColumn(
                    label: Text('type'),
                    tooltip: 'Ordinary or service (1 day only, restricted time)',
                  ),
                  new DataColumn(label: Text('Key')),
                  new DataColumn(label: Text('Check-in')),
                  new DataColumn(label: Text('Check-out')),
                ],
                rows: _listOfRows(snapshot),

              );
            },
          )
```

I couldn't find a way (like a built-in builder) to indicate the document index to pass to the `_listOfRows` function, or how to access the current document for each stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont know what data comes from your stream, but here is on idea on how to do it:

```
 DataTable(
   rows: _createRows(snapshot.data),
 )
```

You want your builder method to return `List<DataRow>`

```
  List<DataRow> _createRows(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {

    List<DataRow> newList = snapshot.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      return new DataRow(cells: _createCellsForElement(documentSnapshot["someDataYouWantToProcessForCellData"]));
    }).toList();

    return newList;
  }
```

You can apply the same logic for cell creation, or you can do it inside the first map function as well.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot! @Tree

Comment: I used same logic in PaginatedDataTable, but sorting by tapping on column header doesn't work. Does sorting work in your case?

Comment: Thank you for this! Could you possibly clarify what you mean by `"someDataYouWantToProcessForCellData"` or provide an example? No matter what I put into it I get the error _The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot'_.

Comment: In answer to my previous comment, here is an example of what can be used in place of the "someDataYouWantToProcessForCellData" placeholder: `return new DataRow(cells: [ DataCell(Text(documentSnapshot.data()['Name'].toString())),`, where `Name` is a field in my Firestore document.

Comment: Please can you show mw how to write the code for ```_createCellsForElement``` @Tree